# How the cricket ball's swing measured instantly?

Tags: cricket, technology, video-review

In the recent test series between India and England, Star Sports, which is the official broadcaster in the Indian sub-continent, showed a new graphics after each ball is bowled. It was the amount of ball swing (in-swing/out-swing). The data was in centimetres & the measuring axis was the trajectory of the ball if it doesn't undergo any swing.

So, what new technology was used to measure this deviation? Or was it just the good old Hawk-eye with some data processing?

Answer (score 2):

This [BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sportacademy/hi/sa/cricket/features/newsid_3625000/3625559.stm) article confirms that Hawk-eye can track any types of bounce, spin, swing and seam with 99.99% accuracy. So, it's basically a hawk-eye that is used to calculate cricket ball's swing instantly.

Answer (score -1):

That's essentially what Hawkeye measures, the path of the ball once it leaves the bowler's hand. In this case it can determine the deviation from the initial trajectory, plot the curve and give measurements though some swift data processing.

The slightly controversial part of Hawkeye is the predictive element, describing what the ball would have done if it had not hit the bat/pad/person of the batsman in the meantime.

Comment: The technology looks derived from Hawkeye but without authentic sources, we cant be sure.

Comment: Whether it's the same machine as Hawkeye or another one, it's the same science.